# IntentService not receiving network state change intents

Tags: android

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have the following...

```
<service
    android:name=".MyIntentService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />"
        <action android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.TEST" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver
    android:name=".MyNetworkMonitor" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />"
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Ideally I'd like the IntentService to 'wake' and interpret the Intent(s) broadcast by the system when either the wi-fi or mobile internet services change state....but it doesn't.

The BroadcastReceiver does receive the Intents, however, and I can get it to send a broadcast intent (`com.mycompany.myapp.TEST`) to wake my IntentService and tell it there has been a change in network state.

So the question is, why won't my IntentService wake from the system intent broadcasts informing of network state change but it will wake from a broadcast from my BroadcastReceiver. Confused.

**EDIT:** This is what you get for trying to code at nearly 5am (oops). For some reason I thought the `com.mycompany.myapp.TEST` intent was working as a broadcast.

What I'm actually doing is `Intent i = new Intent ("com.mycompany.myapp.TEST")` and then using `startService(i)` which works because of the `<intent-filter>` entry (even without explicitly specifying `MyIntentService.class` in the Intent). This is what was confusing the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of the `Intent` message bus as having three channels:

- You can start an activity
- You can start or bind to a service
- You can send a broadcast

These three channels are completely independent of one another. You cannot have a service receive a broadcast, as you are trying to do here, any more than you can have a service receive a start-activity `Intent`.

Please delete the `<intent-filter>` from the service. Then, have your `BroadcastReceiver` call `startService()` on your service (using `new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class)`) when the broadcast arrives.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that I can't start a service with a broadcast. See my edit ay the end of my question for an explanation of why I was getting confused.